# Stepped Value Axes in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, charts, axis, axes

Apologies if this has been asked elsewhere, but unsure of the correct terminology. I am trying to create a chart in Microsoft Excel that has a stepped value axis. The data that is of interest is between a range of -1,000,000 and 0, and between 2,500,000 to 3,000,000. Ideally, I'd create a chart like this:

[image]

My source data looks like this:

[image]

... and ideally I'd create a chart like this:

[image]

(I created this by editing the bounds of the value axis to create a three different ranges, then cut/pasting together)

I can't work out how to do it, and because I'm struggling to describe it I haven't had much luck searching the web (or Stackoverflow) for information.

Can anybody advise me of a) what this is called, and b) how to do it in Excel (if it's possible?). Thanks :)

Comment: What does your data look like? A column chart may do what you  want

Comment: Thanks for the response @cybernetic.nomad... I'll add to the original post.

Comment: This is what a column chart with your data looks like: https://imgur.com/ZAqkbuA  is that what you're looking for? I don't see how your data relates to the first two screencaps in your question.

Comment: That's not quite it. I've mocked up what I'm trying to achieve in Excel by creating three charts, and modifying the bounds to show three different levels of detail, then cutting and pasting together.

Basically, I'd like to be able to set the value axis to use different Units between multiple Bound ranges. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: A log scale (as shown by the screencap in your question) is possible, but only allows for positive values. You could add minor gridlines to a chart, but I think that's the best you can hope for

Comment: Thanks... looks like what I was after isn't possible (although you can get close with a log scale).